# Extend combination of conflicting interfaces in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given these interfaces:

```js
interface A {
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

interface B {
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, pressed: boolean) => void;
}
```

And this interface trying to extend both

```js
interface C extends A, B {
    name: string;
}
```

To be used in this class:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component<C> {
    ...
}
```

I get this compiler error

> Interface 'C' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'.
>     Named property 'onClick' of types 'A' and 'B' are not identical.

After reading the [docs section about declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) I got the impression that such a combination should be possible:

```js
interface C {
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, pressed: boolean) => void;
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}
```

Do I need to define the C interface manually? Or is it possible to produce a combined interface like this through some sort of extend merge like I'm trying to do above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an interface extending both `A` and `B`, if you can provide single signature for `onClick` method which is compatible with `onClick` in both `A` and `B`. In your example, the signature with optional `pressed` parameter is enough:

```
interface AB extends A, B {
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, pressed?: boolean) => void;
}

interface C extends AB {
    name: string;
}
```

Declaration merging probably will not help - for merging to work, merged entities (classes, namespaces, interfaces) must have the same name.